# =SUM(OFFSET to add up rows in one column (MAC Excel)

Tags: worksheet-function

[What would the formula be to add first 7 days and sum then when the formula is copied and pasted to day 14 (in col2) the cell references increment so that it ads days 8-14 and sums those days in col2?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQhoW.png)

Answer (score 0):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(A2,7)<>0,"",SUM($B$1:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: IF(MOD(B4,7)<>0,"",SUM($C$3:C4)-SUM($D3:D$3))   This is the formula I put in.  B4 was the first cell with day 1 in it.  C3 was column header, C4 was first cell with amount.  D3 was column header.  The 7 day total inserted in the day 6 cell (colC)